How to enable the torch with expo-camera in SDK 51.0.0?
I'm trying to enable the torch in my Expo application using the expo-camera package with SDK 51.0.0.
Environment
Expo SDK Version: 51.0.0
Platforms: Android, iOS
Dependencies:
expo-camera
react-native
@react-native-async-storage/async-storage
@react-navigation/native
import { CameraView, useCameraPermissions } from 'expo-camera';
import React, { useState, useContext, useCallback } from 'react';
import { Button, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { AppContext } from "../../context/AppContext";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';
import styles from './ScanEnterGTINScreenStyles';

const ScanEnterGTINScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [permission, requestPermission] = useCameraPermissions();
  const [scannedData, setScannedData] = useState(null);
  const [isScanning, setIsScanning] = useState(true);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const { t } = useContext(AppContext);
  const [isFlashOn, setIsFlashOn] = useState(false);

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      setIsScanning(true);
      setScannedData(null);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, [])
  );

  if (!permission) {
    return <View />;
  }

  if (!permission.granted) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>We need your permission to show the camera</Text>
        <Button onPress={requestPermission} title="grant permission" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  const handleBarcodeScanned = ({ data }) => {
    // Processing scanned data
  };

  const toggleFlash = () => {
    setIsFlashOn(!isFlashOn);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <CameraView
        style={styles.camera}
        onBarcodeScanned={handleBarcodeScanned}
        flashMode={isFlashOn ? 'torch' : 'off'}
      />
      <View style={styles.overlay}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.flashlightButton}
          onPress={toggleFlash}
        >
          <Text style={styles.flashlightText}>{isFlashOn ? 'Flash Off' : 'Flash On'}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

export default ScanEnterGTINScreen;


For those who may land here.
Flashmode is no more. Use enableTorch.
Try:
    enableTorch= { cameraTorch }
     <CameraView
            style={styles.camera}
            onBarcodeScanned={handleBarcodeScanned}
            enableTorch={isFlashOn}
          />

It's a simple boolean.
Documentation
This may take a second to turn the flash on.
